# Can't create gcloud cloudsql instance through Google sql library. (not authorized to make this request)

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-sql, gcloud

I'm able to create a cloudsql instance though the use of Google's SDK, but I'm not able to create it through the Google's sqladmin library.

I keep getting

`googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/kentik-testing-175821/instances?alt=json returned "The client is not authorized to make this request.">`

I've followed these instructions https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/python-guide.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Been stuck at this all weekend.

this is my history I believe. Hard to tell as I've tired so many things.

  `625  gcloud auth application-default login
  626  gcloud auth application-default login
  627  unset GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
  628  pip3 install --upgrade google-api-python-client
  629  gcloud auth application-default login
  630  env
  631  env | grep GOOGLE
  632  ls
  633  kentik
  634  cd intern-test-suite/
  635  ls
  636  chmod +x test.py
  637  ./test.py
  638  gcloud projects status
  639  gcloud projects list
  640  ./test.py kentik-testing-175821
  641  ./test.py kentik-testing-175821 rsim-testing
  642  cd
  643  ls
  644  which gcloud
  645  gcloud auth login
  646  gcloud auth application-default --help
  647  history`

Comment: post history of what you did please

Comment: Is the history I typed helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set the the env GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = to to where the SDK created credentials were.

`export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/Users/<YOUR USER NAME>/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json`

I according the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials) you didn't need to do this, but it seemed to be my fix.